# MRI-CT paired Open Dataset for MRI synthesis from CT using Supervised Learning

Tags: data-request, medical, images, global, deep-learning

I'm finding MR-CT *Paired* images to do some experiments on [synthesize MRI from CT images](https://qims.amegroups.com/article/view/41784/html) using [U-Net Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-Net).

However I still have struggling finding these *free* datasets.

I've tried finding *Open datasets*  at [*Dataset Search*](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/) on Google but the most relevant one is this one on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/chenghanpu/brain-tumor-mri-and-ct-scan). But it doesn't have license and have some problems at the [discussion](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/chenghanpu/brain-tumor-mri-and-ct-scan/discussion/358956).

I've also tried finding on [IEEE DataPort](https://ieee-dataport.org/datasets) but I couldn't find things I want.

Could anyone please give me some Sites to find this kind of Dataset?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the SynthRAD2023 grand challenge:
https://synthrad2023.grand-challenge.org/